# $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$.

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I want to find 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}dx
$$
The integrand is continuous at $0$, so $f(z):=\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^2}$ is entire. By the Residue Theorem,
$$
0=\int_{C_R} f(z)dz+\int_{-R}^R f(z)dz,
$$
where $C_R$ is the semicircular contour of radius $R$ centered at $0$ in the upper half-plane (oriented counterclockwise). Now
$$
\int_{C_R}f(z)dz= \int_0^\pi \frac{1-\cos(Re^{i\theta})}{R^2e^{i2\theta}}Rie^{i\theta}d\theta=\int_0^\pi \frac{1-\cos(Re^{i\theta})}{R}ie^{-i\theta}d\theta,
$$
which does not seem easily manageable.

Differentiating under the integral sign works naively, by letting
$$
I(a):=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}dx
$$
then $I'(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $I(0)=0$. The issue is that the derivative of the integrand is not integrable, so the passage of the limit into the integral is not legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View your integrand as the real part of

$$\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$$

then integrate over an indented semicircle in the upper half-plane.

The details in full are worked on on page 44 of Stein and Shakarchi's "Complex Analysis"

---

I hope this helps ^_^